# Multiple AJAX form submission through AntiForgery Token

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have used AntiForgeryToken to handle the multiple form submissions the code is as follow

```
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
       string _antiForgToken =  request.Form.GetValues("__RequestVerificationToken")[0];
       if (ctx.Session["userform"] != null)
       {
           if (_antiForgToken.Equals(ctx.Session["userform"].ToString()))
           {
               //kill the request                   
               response.StatusCode = 400;
               response.StatusDescription = "Bad Request.";                   
           }
       }
       else
           ctx.Session["userform"] = _antiForgToken;

    }
```

the code works fine on the (normal)forms but it gives problem when the form is posted via ajax multiple times (that is a required feature) i have a form say for example `Add Contacts` the user add a contact `phone` and press enter the (ajax)request is completed normally but again in the same form the user selects email and press enter here i get the error because the `AntiforgeryToken` is the same which was generated earlier my question is how can i refresh the `AntiForgeryToken` on ajax success

Comment: See this:- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271085/how-can-i-use-multiple-ajax-forms-with-antiforgery-validation-on-the-same-mvc3-p

Comment: @KhumeshKumawat it is not the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the solution but it seems stable:

[Preventing CSRF With Ajax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx)

Comment: i have gone through the article but it seems to resolve the json posting issue ...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a custom AntiForgery token by calling following function inside your razor view.

```
@functions{
  public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
  {
    string cookieToken, formToken;
    System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
    return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
  }
}
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'xxx',
  data: data,
  headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': GetAntiForgeryToken()},
  success: function (data) {
    //if success
  },
  error: function (e) {
    //if error
  }
});
</script>
```

And now inside your Attribute Filter you can validate it using the following code:

```
string tokenValue = request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
{
    string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(':');
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
    {
      cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
      formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
    }
}
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
```